# how can i show or hide layers of a psd file in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am working on an application for visually impaired people . I was wondering if it would be possible to use psd files with multiple layers , for example a layer of high contrast, a layer of medium contrast and one with small contrast and change these layers with Xcode for example with gestures . I would appreciate any help . Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why does it have to be PSD?  Why not three separate PNG files?

Answer (score 1):

PSD is native to adobe photoshop and can't be used in OSX applications (or not easily), you might be better off exporting separate layers with different transparency/opacity to .PNG files, then using the gestures to overlay the images on top of each other.